# How to extract data from a non animated gif file using python

Tags: python, graph, statistics

Newbie to python and doing some tutorials on how to use Python. I have now been tasked to use a non animated GIF graph to create a predication. 
Im not looking for the code to do this but direction on what to use. 
So far matplotlib and PIl are the libraries which I think are required .
Reason being is to create a graph I use matplotlib's pyplot. 
How do I now take the end result image and retrieve x and y axis data from it?
I will be using a list of .gif images as source data to create a prediction.

Regards,
Romano

Comment: Do you mean x, y axis data as in height and width of image or a specific x, y coordinate? If the first case you could use numpy (height, width = img.shape[:2])

Comment: HI Kavko, I think I might need to clarify here a bit. I went to deep not knowing what I actually needed to do. I was given a few gif files which have an x axis showing date and a y axis showing colors . the gif was of a area and on the map showed the precipitation according to the color scheme on the y axis. I assumed I would need to retrieve the values from this file in that manner.  However on the link posted previously I found that this was not needed and I used scipy to import the file. When i compared the output of the file i read vs another file it was the same. My code was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the below link is partly what I need to use . 
http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/#opening-and-writing-to-image-files